# New row is based on the data of prevouse row, how to prevent from duplication

Tags: php, mysql

This is the table,

```
tbl_example:

ID -    unique -   auto increment,
name-   text
num-   Notunique
created  timestamp   curentdatetime
```

**Using php5.5 and msyql5.5**
every insert, first it gets the value of num from the table based on the updated time been inserted for example this is the query to get the last column **Num** value:

> $sql1 = "SELECT num FROM tbl_example ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 1"

NOW as it got the value of last row of been added, with **create** column timestamp, the new query for insert will be for example:

```
 $sql2 "INSERT INTO tbl_example (name, num) VALUES ('TEMPNAME', $sql1 + 1)"
```

NOTE: here I only added the $sql1 in the query which functionaly doesn't not return value but to only make my question understandable.

As here the value of column **num** will be based on the result of $sql1,

$question: if tow user or three use runs the query in same second exact time same so the result of the $sql1 will be same for three of them, as on the $sql2 the data will insert and the value of the **num column** will be same for three of them,

For some reason I can not keep the column **num** unique,

How I can prevent a duplication in such case.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go [here](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/pdo.lastinsertid.php), they explain how to use [`lastinsertid`](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/pdo.lastinsertid.php).
This is what you're looking for.

If you want to do it in one query separated by semicolons, this is all about query and SQL, not Php.

Something like this should do the job:

```
SET @tmp=(SELECT MAX(NUM)+1 FROM tbl_example);
LOCK TABLES tbl_example READ;
INSERT INTO tbl_example (name, num) VALUES ('TEMPNAME', @tmp);
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

But your problem seems like it's a database design and a lack of client-server and SQL knowledge...

Comment: I upvoted , nomatter you adress as an alternative the same solution I suggested (just by adding a temp lock ). The reason is you corretly point out (as you do in my answer comment the use of  lastinsertid)

Comment: i think the lock tables statement is missing the lock type and therefore that query would not work.
also it would have enormous performance issues if he really has 2-3 concurrent executions.
shouldn't a transaction be enough ?

Comment: @Stormsson Yes you're perfectly right. Anyway when I watch his history, the user seems not to care about the answers, so I've lost enough time to answering to such kind of people, sorry man...

Comment: @OlivierPons you are right about the user, but someone else in the future could need this answer. 
Many times i've been "saved"  by old answers.
The syntax is stil wrong: the lock_type must be put after the table list

Comment: @OlivierPons  sorry, i had net disconnection, as my place some time happens now i am trying to implement your answer let me see if it works for me

Comment: @OlivierPons regarding the, the database design here i have a different case, i have to use hijri(arabic calender) and every year the num column starts from value 1 and ends at last second of the year then again starts from one and auto increment tell end of the year and so on.

Comment: You mean you insert every second one value?

Comment: no, i just want to be sure the the query will not allow to be duplicated, as the column is not unique so locking the talbe(you answer is good) but only problem it will make the application to run slow i have used ur answer dont know it's giving some error can u please check the answer back. regards

Comment: LOCK TABLES `dab_test` READ;
INSERT INTO `dab_test` (name, num) VALUES ('TEMPNAME',1 + SELECT num from `dab_test` ORDER BY created DESC limit 1
)
UNLOCK TABLES `dab_test`;----------error

Comment: @OlivierPons, when i (LOCK TABLES dab_test Read) here i can read but how i can insert, it's lock?????ERROR 1099 (HY000): Table 'dab_test' was locked with a READ lock and can't be up

Comment: @abas_rafiq I've updated my answer tell me if it works. But it's less safe. It just forbids reading as long as you've not written your value. So it should be still safe.

Comment: @OlivierPons i runed yoru query not work,i tried, 
SET @tmp=(select num + 1 from tbl_example order by created DESC limit 1);
INSERT INTO tbl_example (name, num) VALUES ('TEMPNAME', @tmp);
---------- this works but when i try with lock-----
SET @tmp=(select num + 1 from dab_test order by created DESC limit 1);
LOCK TABLES dab_test READ;
INSERT INTO dab_test (name, num) VALUES ('TEMPNAME', @tmp);
UNLOCK TABLES; --- it says table is locked

Comment: Connect to mysql command line & try to find as long as it doesn't work.... it took me 4s to try and find out I was missing parenthesis. Edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: SET @tmp=(SELECT MAX(NUM)+1 FROM dab_test);----------success--------
LOCK TABLES dab_test READ;---------success-----------
INSERT INTO dab_test (name, num) VALUES ('TEMPNAME', @tmp);--error---ERROR 1099 (HY000): Table 'dab_test' was locked with a READ lock and can't be up
dated------------------------
UNLOCK TABLES;------success-------------- so it mean not inserting when lock

Comment: So it's not READ but WRITE, knowing that it has a high priority and may narrow down possible duplicate problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_example (name, num) select 'TEMPNAME', MAX(num)+1 from tbl_example
```

or, if you still need the sorting by date:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_example (name, num) select 'TEMPNAME', num+1 from tbl_example order by created DESC limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use an [select into](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html) so as to do the insert in the same time:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_example (name, num) VALUES (name, num)
  SELECT  tbl_example.name,   Max(tbl_example.num)+1
    FROM tbl_example GROUP BY tbl_example.num
```

Comment: I can't avoid using bold. Because your suggestion is very dangerous. Never **NEVER EVER USE** `MAX()` to do an INSERT. Never. This is simply **not safe at all**. **Use the database server: it's his job**, not yours, and use lastinsertid().

Comment: @Olivier Pons, i am agree with u, so what if we insert kind like, insert into value select, for exampel(INSERT INTO `testdb`.`tbl_test` (`id`, `name`, `num`, `created`) VALUES ('2', 'name2',(select num from tbl_test order by created DESC limit 1)+1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);

Comment: I've updated my answer accordingly so you get the idea.

Comment: @OlivierPons, I agree, with you. However the "dangerous" part you are adressing is a bit relative.The worst thing that can happen is to have a duplicate field. This matter is however avoided with better database structure (the role of auto inc seems to play no part on the table)...If is something more dangerous I am not aware of please clarify

Comment: You're perfectly right: better database structure. The problem is about database design. You say `The worst thing that can happen is to have a duplicate field`. Exaclty. And that's not a minor problem, not a major problem: it's a *critical* problem...

Comment: thanks from all,as it's standard if we don't want a column duplicate we can keep it unique, but here case is different,(num column every year will start from value- 1 and then auto increment tell end of the year, and again next year starts from 1,so in year i don't want the num to be duplicate if i keep it unique next year same colum will have the value of last year so then it will not accept that's why i keep it not unique and try to prevent duplication in year.